# Error type conversion resulting in urllib.request.urlopen it wont work as character strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

In python 3.x, after taking the value of url (urllib.request.urlopen)

```
sock = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
code = sock.read (100)
code = code.replace( '\n' , 'enter' )
code = code.replace( '\t' ,  'tab'  )
```

I can not treat 'code' as strings of characters, it returns an error of type conversion

```
code = code.replace( '\n' , 'enter' )
code = code.replace( '\t' ,  'tab'  )
```

Comment: What is `f.sock(100)`? How does it relate to the `urllib.request.urlopen()` response?

Comment: You should include the actual Traceback you received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before writing:

```
code = code.replace('\n', 'enter')
code = code.replace('\t', 'tab')
```

Write this:

```
code = code.decode('utf-8')
```

Finally, your code becomes:

```
code = code.decode('utf-8')
code = code.replace('\n', 'enter')
code = code.replace('\t', 'tab')
```

urllib.request.urlopen returns bytes data

Note: Because you have f.sock, if you have a judgment urllib.request.urlopen?

Comment: I'm wrong to write, the instruction is "code.decode (...)" Thanks

Comment: Works perfect on my phone and my laptop with android pyton3.

Comment: Note that the assumption that the response is UTF-8 cannot always be made. **It depends on the exact response**.

Answer (score 2):

`urllib.request` returns *bytes values*.

Either decode to a string, or use byte literals when replacing:

```
code = code.replace(b'\n', b'enter')
code = code.replace(b'\t', b'tab')
```

Decoding requires that you know what codec was used for the textual content. You can see if a content character set was returned:

```
codec = sock.info().get_param('charset')
```

If that value is not `None` you can decode with that codec:

```
code = code.decode(codec)
```

The default codec for `text/` mimetype responses is ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1), but HTML responses often set the desired codec in a `<meta>` tag in the header. Leave decoding that to a competent HTML parser, like BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I have a problem with my python3 interpreter of my android mobile phone, because the sentence code.replace code = (b '\ n', b'enter ') is not recognized.

But in the console of my laptop works perfect.